# Stuck trying to return a list from a predicate to another predicate

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a prolog program that solves square crossword puzzles. They are described by the predicates dimension(X) and black(X,Y), representing the dimension of the crossword and the coordinates of the black squares on the grid respectively.

I want to make a list of variables representing all the spots on the crossword that words can fit in, meaning all horizontal and vertical consecutive white squares (uninterrupted by black squares). I have started with the horizontal spots first, I store the white squares until a black is encountered or I reach the end of the line, then I remove those from the list to not go through them again, then removes the black ones, and repeat the process.

Although via printing I can see the result is the intended one, the list is never returned to the main predicate and the output is "no". I will provide the code and the printed values:

```
dimension(5).
black(1,3).
black(2,3).
black(3,2).
black(4,3).
black(5,1).
black(5,5).
words([adam,al,as,do,lis,ma,oker,ore,pirus,po,so,ur]).

crossword(L):-
    squares(Squares),
    generate_x_variables(Squares, 1, L).

squares(List):-
    dimension(Dimension),
    findall(X-Y, (between(1, Dimension, X), between(1, Dimension, Y)), List).


    
    generate_x_variables([], _, []).
    generate_x_variables(Squares, Row, [Variable|Variables]):-
        take_while(is_white_square, Squares, Row, Variable),
        write("Variable:    "), write(Variable), nl,
        drop_while(is_white_square, Squares, Row, RemainingSquares),
        drop_while(is_black_square, RemainingSquares, Row, UpdatedRemainingSquares),
        nth0(0, UpdatedRemainingSquares, X-Y),
        (X \= Row -> TempRow is Row + 1 ; TempRow is Row),
        generate_x_variables(UpdatedRemainingSquares, TempRow, Variables)
 
    
take_while(_, [], Row, []).
take_while(Predicate, [X-Y|Xs], Row, [X-Y|Taken]):-
    call(Predicate, X-Y, Row),
    take_while(Predicate, Xs, Row, Taken).
take_while(Predicate, [X-Y|_], Row, []) :-
    \+ call(Predicate, X-Y, Row).
    
is_white_square(X-Y, Row):-
    \+ black(X, Y),
    X=:=Row.

is_black_square(X-Y, Row):-
    black(X, Y),
    X=:=Row.

drop_while(_, [], Row, []).
drop_while(Predicate, [X-Y|Xs], Row, Remaining):-
    call(Predicate, X-Y, Row),
    drop_while(Predicate, Xs, Row, Remaining).
drop_while(Predicate, [X-Y|Xs], Row, [X-Y|Xs]) :-
    \+ call(Predicate, X-Y, Row).
    
nth0(0, [X|_], X).
nth0(N, [_|Xs], Element) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    nth0(N1, Xs, Element).
```

The printed values:

Variable:    [1 - 1, 1 - 2]

Variable:    [1 - 4, 1 - 5]

Variable:    [2 - 1, 2 - 2]

Variable:    [2 - 4, 2 - 5]

Variable:    [3 - 1]

Variable:    [3 - 3, 3 - 4, 3 - 5]

Variable:    [4 - 1, 4 - 2]

Variable:    [4 - 4, 4 - 5]

Variable:    []

Variable:    [5 - 2, 5 - 3, 5 - 4]

So why is L not a list of these variables back in the main predicate?

EDIT: Thanks to @Scott Hunter I fixed the issue but a new one appeared. It now prints the required list but allows me to keep clicking "more" an infinite amount of times, adding empty lists to my results. The problem with the initial code was that the predicate nth0 didn't handle the case where its' input list was empty.

```
    generate_x_variables([], Row, _):-
    dimension(Dimension),
    Row > Dimension.
generate_x_variables(Squares, Row, [Variable|Variables]):-
    write("Squares list    "), write(Squares), nl,
    take_while(is_white_square, Squares, Row, Variable),
    write("Variable taken:    "), write(Variable), nl,
    drop_while(is_white_square, Squares, Row, RemainingSquares),
    write("After removing whites:    "), write(RemainingSquares), nl,
    drop_while(is_black_square, RemainingSquares, Row, UpdatedRemainingSquares),
    write("After removing blacks:    "), write(UpdatedRemainingSquares), nl, 
    nth0(0, UpdatedRemainingSquares, X-Y),
    write("First element of rest:   "), write(X-Y), nl,
    (X \= Row -> TempRow is Row + 1 ; TempRow is Row),
    write("Current row:    "), write(TempRow),  nl,
    generate_x_variables(UpdatedRemainingSquares, TempRow, Variables).
```

Comment: Have you verified that `generate_x_variables([], _, [])` is ever reached?

Comment: No because i thought that if that were the case then the program would be stuck in an infinite loop. You are right, i added a print in there and it never shows. How does the recursion stop then?

Comment: I think I found my problem, thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction I was stuck hours here.